# Adding custom cells in Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I have a UITableView which contains a prototype cell, with components added onto it in the storyboard, and referenced in my CustomCell.h & .m files, with the CustomCell.cs looking like this:

```
public partial class CustomCell : UITableViewCell
{
    public CustomCell(IntPtr handle) : base(handle)
    {

    }

    public UILabel Sender
    {
        get
        {
            return senderLabel;
        }
        set
        {
            senderLabel = value;
        }
    }

    public UILabel Subject
    {
        get
        {
            return subjectLabel;
        }
        set
        {
            subjectLabel = value;
        }
    }

    public UILabel Date
    {
        get
        {
            return timeLabel;
        }
        set
        {
            timeLabel = value;
        }
    }

    public UILabel Preview
    {
        get
        {
            return previewLabel;
        }
        set
        {
            previewLabel = value;
        }
    }

    public UILabel Initials
    {
        get
        {
            return initialsLabel;
        }
        set
        {
            initialsLabel = value;
        }
    }
}
```

This custom cell is then used in my table's source file, and its GetCell method, to try and add data to the table:

```
CustomCell cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell("MailCell") as CustomCell;
cell.Sender.Text = TableItems[indexPath.Row].Sender;
cell.Subject.Text = TableItems[indexPath.Row].Subject;
cell.Preview.Text = TableItems[indexPath.Row].Preview;
cell.Date.Text = TableItems[indexPath.Row].Time;
cell.Initials.Text = "";
```

When you run the program and try and add the data to the table, it breaks on the second line of the GetCell method with a NullReferenceException, which implies that their is either no label in the cell, or that there is no cell to edit. My prototype's cell has an identifier of "MailCell", and I have tried making a full constructor in the class, which didn't work. I had previously programmatically added in the components into the table's cell's, and that worked perfectly and therefore I can be sure that my code to add the data to the source works as intended, and is not the problem. What else is there possible to test?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It breaks because it can not find an instance of you custom cell for the very first row.
DequeueReusableCell is looking for an instance if it can not find one it returns null

Change your code to:

```
CustomCell cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell("MailCell") as CustomCell ?? new CustomCell();
```

Comment: That code also breaks as there is no formal constructor in my CustomCell class for when I say `new CustomCell()`; I only have the IntPtr one. Should I add an empty constructor?

Comment: That might be helpfull, yes.